# what happens If I remove mysql-bin.index file?

Tags: mysql, innodb, binlog, mysqlbinlog, mariadb-10.4

Because of the file storage full, we are removing mysql bin log files.

Accidentally, we removed `mysql-bin.index` file.

What happens if I remove `mysql-bin.index` file?

These below are my DBMS info. Thank you.

```
MariaDB 10.4
Single Instance
engine: InnoDB Engine
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you erased all the binary logs, the `mysql-bin.index` can also go.

Do you still need binary logging ? You must restart MariaDB, and the mysqld process will recreate `mysql-bin.index` it for you.

If you no longer want binary logging, you must comment out `log-bin` from the MariaDB config file. You still need to restart MariaDB.